# How to listen to tabs.onUpdated only and block tabs.onActivated after the creation of a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension listens for both onActivated and onUpdated. In the instance when the user opens a new tab, both listeners fire their functions with onActivated first and then the onUpdated.

The problem is, my function for both listeners are identical, so I only want onUpdated to fire its function and block onActivated in this specific case.

So basically I want:

- user refreshes the page: onUpdated fires function
- user changes active tab: onActivated fires function
- user opens a new tab:    onActivated is blocked while onUpdated fires its function

I've tried to use if statements in onActivated to check for onUpdated but failed to gain my required results.

```
function saveDataAndLogTime(tab) { ... };

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        saveDataAndLogTime(tab);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab) {
        saveDataAndLogTime(tab);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Declare a global variable that stores `Date.now()` and tabId inside, then your  saveDataAndLogTime will check the time difference (if tab id is identical) and just return from the function doing nothing of that difference is smaller than say 100ms.

Comment: So, you're basically saying. Let both functions run but implement a check inside saveDataAndLogTime.

Comment: Ok, I think got what I wanted. It was as easy as denying function activity if a difference is smaller than 1000ms. Thanks @wOxxOm!

Comment: @wOxxOm Damn son. Is there no other api?